# How to root Oppo Realme 2

Tags: rooting

I couldn't find a guide online to root my Oppo Realme 2 (RMX1805, Color OS Version 6.0, Android Version 9). So how can I root my Oppo Realme 2?

Update: I have unlocked my bootloader following the instructions [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/realme-2/how-to/guide-to-unlock-bootloader-realme-c1-t3966734).

Comment: [Oppo/Oneplus .ozip Firmware decrypter](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/convert-ozip-to-zip-for-installing-stock-rom-firmware-from-twrp-orangefox-etc.4065277)

Answer (score 2):

first step is unlock bootloader, which you have done already. i will post this step as mandatory

**1) unlock bootloader: WARNING all data lost**

- download latest [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) to PC
- enable [OEM unlocking](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/enable-oem-unlocking-on-android) in developer options
- reboot device into bootloader mode (keep holding <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> while rebooting or power on device with <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>)
- connect device with usb cable and install [usb drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) for PC
- navigate to folder `platform-tools` from [cmd.exe](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10)
- unlock bootloader from fastboot (confirm with <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>)

  ```
  fastboot devices
  fastboot flashing unlock
  ```

---

**2) boot custom recovery without modifying/flashing device**

- download custom recovery [TWRP](https://www.cyanogenmods.org/twrp-recovery-for-realme-2-download) into `platform-tools` folder
- boot TWRP from fastboot (do not flash)

  ```
  fastboot boot twrp.img
  ```
- **DO NOT swipe** to allow modifications of system
- wait 30 seconds then install adb [usb drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) for PC
- tap the icon <kbd>≡</kbd> lower right corner and check the log for
  **a)** `Data successfully decrypted` (or no error)
  **b)** `Failed to mount '/data'`

---

**3) dump the current boot partition from device** (depending on mounting `/data` a) successful or b) failed)

- **a**) backup `boot.emmc.win` from TWRP

  - *TWRP* - tap *Backup* - select *Boot* partition
  - copy `TWRP/BACKUPS` folder to PC via [MTP](https://thegeekpage.com/fix-mtp-not-working-in-windows-10)
- **b**) backup `boot.img` from adb

  ```
  adb devices
  adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/boot boot.emmc.win
  ```

---

**edit:** (other method)

- **c) extract boot.img from OTA (stock ROM) with ozipdecrypt.py**
  if for whatever reason TWRP is not available (or not booting) you still can find stock ROM for your device. However, flashing boot.img from download is risky, make 100% sure that this build number is matching your device

  ```
  ro.build.description=S88051AA1-user 9 PKQ1.190319.001 eng.root.20190830.025347 release-keys
  ro.build.display.full_id=RMX1805_11_A.60_190830
  ```

  - install [Python 3.8.2](https://www.python.org)
  - install pycryptodome

    ```
    pip3.exe install pycryptodome
    ```
  - download and extract [oppo_ozip_decrypt-master.zip](https://github.com/bkerler/oppo_ozip_decrypt)
  - download [stock ROM](https://download.c.realme.com/osupdate/RMX1805EX_11_OTA_0600_all_LtoqeM8aS1Gq.ozip)
  - run `ozipdecrypt.py` from [cmd.exe](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10)

    ```
    python.exe ozipdecrypt.py RMX1805EX_11_OTA_0600_all_LtoqeM8aS1Gq.ozip
    ```
  - check folder `out` and rename `out\boot.img` into `boot.emmc.win` (just to not confuse with encrypted boot.img, name of file doesn't matter)

    [image: oppo_ozip_decrypt.png]

    (i have uploaded the converted stock ROM [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/v3j0rrxni6w0crd), `recovery.img` is missing)

---

**4) root your device with Magisk**

- **a**) install Magisk directly from TWRP (may brick device)

  - copy [Magisk-v20.4.zip](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#introduction) to Storage or MicroSD via [MTP](https://thegeekpage.com/fix-mtp-not-working-in-windows-10)
  - *TWRP* - tap *Install* - select `Magisk-v20.4.zip` - *Swipe to confirm Flash*
  - reboot device (*TWRP* - tap *Reboot* - tap *System*)

---

- **b**) patch `boot.emmc.win` "offline" with Magisk Manager

  - reboot device (*TWRP* - tap *Reboot* - tap *System*)
  - copy `boot.emmc.win` to Internal Storage via [MTP](https://thegeekpage.com/fix-mtp-not-working-in-windows-10)
  - install + launch [MagiskManager-v7.5.1.apk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#introduction)
  - enable *Advanced Settings* - ***Preserve force encryption***
  - tap on *Install (1)* - *Install (2)* - *Select and Patch a File*
  - allow permissions for storage
  - navigate to Internal Storage and select `boot.emmc.win`
    (this will start patching immediately but does not modify your device - no worry the text "Flashing.." is misleading)

    [image: Install-Magisk-on-Android-using-Patched-Boot-Image-01.jpg]

    ---

    **(5) flash the rooted boot image from fastboot**

    - copy `magisk_patched.img` to PC via [MTP](https://thegeekpage.com/fix-mtp-not-working-in-windows-10)
    - reboot device into bootloader mode (keep holding <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> while rebooting or power on device with <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>)
    - boot `magisk_patched.img` without modifying/flashing device (for testing purposes)

      ```
      fastboot devices
      fastboot boot magisk_patched.img
      ```
    - if it works: reboot device into bootloader mode
    - flash `magisk_patched.img` to boot partition (may brick device)

      ```
      fastboot flash boot magisk_patched.img
      fastboot reboot
      ```

---

**Unbricking** (method b) only)

- reboot device into bootloader mode (keep holding <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> while rebooting or power on device with <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>)
- flash your backup of original `boot.emmc.win` from fastboot

  ```
  fastboot devices
  fastboot flash boot boot.emmc.win
  fastboot reboot
  ```

Comment: In the second step, not able to boot TWRP from fastboot. It shows "booting... FAILED (remote: unknown reason)"

Comment: TWRP is not requirement.. update question with screenshot of device info build number (settings - about phone) so we can search for boot.img

Answer (score 1):

I think the ROOT of Oppo phones is not too difficult because it has Recovery Mode by itself, can directly flash ROOT files.

**Important:** Please backup your data and download the original ROM file on OPPO homepage before doing so, in case of any possible uncertainties.
Now, all you need to do is download the SuperSU file, save it to the storage device or SD card.

Download this file: [SuperSU 2.82 SR5](https://download.chainfire.eu/1220/SuperSU/SR5-SuperSU-v2.82-SR5-20171001224502.zip?retrieve_file=1)

If it does not work, try with this file, it works on most Oppo devices (however, this is not the latest version of SuperSU, but it is still fully supported): [OPPO SuperSU](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Ooe5t7GK6r5tPr0aW6-IakCIIXa1pDO/view?usp=sharing)

Next, turn off the phone. Now start pressing Volume Down and Power keys together for a few moments. Wait for a while, the screen will display the language selection menu, it supports English, Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese. Here, we choose English. You can move options with the volume up and down keys, select them with the power key, or you can press directly on the screen.

In the ColorOS RECOVERY options panel, select `Install from storage device`, navigate to the SuperSU file you just selected and flash it.

Before rebooting, go to `Wipe data` then wipe cache.

Everything is completed, when you reboot, on the phone screen will appear SuperSU, you have successfully ROOT!

Note: Using this method SuperSU will be saved to the system partition. Ie you will not be able to uninstall it but can turn it off as other system applications. To remove ROOT, go to Oppo homepage, download the original ROM, then use the above method to reinstall the operating system.

Good luck.

Comment: How can unsigned zip flashed from stock recovery?

Comment: @alecxs If you need to restore the original ROM of the manufacturer, follow the above method.
ColorOS RECOVERY is a simple recovery, it is not as functional and difficult to use as CWM Recovery or TWRP, but it meets the needs of inexperienced users, easy to use without worrying about damaging the system operating.
If you have installed TWRP or CWM Recovery, you will not lose them when you restore using the manufacturer ROM file, but if you want to remove TWRP or CWM Recovery to use ColorOS RECOVERY, you must to flash manufacturer ROM with `SP Flashtool`.

Comment: of course you can flash **OEM-signed** OTA zip from ColorOS Recovery. but SuperSU is not signed with oppo certificates. if it is true what you say, this is a big surprise and security vulnerability

Comment: ColorOS Recovery is different from OTA. With the default OTA on your phone, your device must not have ROOT, but with ColorOS Recovery, it's like developer mode, rescue your phone when something goes wrong, not just an OS update .
Not a security vulnerability, it's a great way to save your phone.