# Use a phone without a screen

Tags: screen, broken-screen

I have a very peculiar situation/question. Below is my mom's phone, OPPO F5 to be precise. It had a broken screen a long time ago. I removed the broken screen, as it posed threat to my siblings, as it could injure them without us knowing. Then, i decided to buy a new screen from OPPO service centre to fix this problem myself. As it is now a lock down period, most/all service centres are not available. I could wait till the lock down is over, but my question is, can you use the phone, like have the screen displayed/ported to a laptop, by wired means(i have no access to the phone's applications or any other forms, as there is no touch screen to control them), to use the phone, till the lock down is over? The phone functions normally by all means, as you can see from the picture, that there is the notification light is still on. `Hey Google` is also working partially, as when i say it, there is vibration, but no response by the assistant. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: When i connect that phone to my laptop, it is charging but isnt detected by my laptop as a device.

[image: OPPO CPH1723 without a screen]

Comment: Please check the wiki for the tag [`broken-screen`](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) for possible options.

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc

Comment: @alecxs Scrcpy cant work in my situation, as the phone isn't detected by the computer. Moreover, i cannot control the phone to enable adb connection.

Comment: ... then you know the answer

Comment: @alecxs Dead end.

Comment: except for USB-OTG operating blind (with earphones you might hear click noises, but chance you get adb authorized is low) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could try doing is flashing a custom recovery onto your phone, then get USB debugging permission using the custom recovery, to then launch a screen control software to control your phone.

Every phone have a different way of installing a custom recovery, I remember Oppo phones need edl to install one, you can search up "oppo f5 recovery custom recovery" to find the custom recovery and install method.

After that, get adb, start adb by `adb start-server`. Next, reboot into recovery mode, it can be done by doing a button combination.

You can then push a key file in your `.android` folder when your device is detected as in recovery, if you are on Ubuntu, it is in `~/.android`. Push the adb_keys in the folder to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`, use `adb push ~/.android/adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys`

After that, run all these commands to finish our work:

```
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
cd /
echo "persist.service.adb.enable=1" >> default.prop 
echo "persist.service.debuggable=1" >> default.prop
echo "persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb" >> default.prop
echo "persist.service.adb.enable=1" >> /system/build.prop
echo "persist.service.debuggable=1" >> /system/build.prop
echo "persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb" >> /system/build.prop
```

After that, type `reboot` to reboot to system, you should now be able to use scrcpy to control your screen.

Comment: won't work on locked bootloader because of AVB. btw it's a Mediatek device you probably meant preloader mode (EDL mode is for Qualcomm)

Comment: @alecxs I don't know it is a mediatek, but this device HAVE recovery available online

Comment: might work if TWRP is AVBv1 signed (which you can do with AIK) but will fail for AVBv2. readback from SP Flash Tool would be option to get a full dump of userdata partition (should be restoreable after unlocking bootloader) another option some user claimed security vulnerability in [ColorOS Recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223444) if that is true one could create a flashable zip which does the necessary modifications and set `ro.adb.secure=0` (only userdebug/eng builds) instead of placing adb_keys

Comment: If you can actually get a full dump of the data partition then modify it to then send it back, that would be awesome

Comment: unfortunately dump is encrypted and can only decrypted on this origin unique device itself (dump *userdata + metadata* to be exactly) and (unsigned) modified *system* would not boot