# After unlocking a boot loader, is rooting different among phones?

Tags: rooting

After unlocking a boot loader, is the process of rooting different  among phones?

Comment: Hello. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Well i'm asking the question I asked.   At the same time I happen to be trying to root my oppo phone that I unlocked the bootloader of

Comment: The answer is **yes**. Rooting is different, sometimes each device model requires different steps.

Comment: [How to root Oppo Realme 2](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223444) // [Oppo/Oneplus .ozip Firmware decrypter](https://github.com/bkerler/oppo_ozip_decrypt/blob/master/README.md#tutorial) // [Magisk Installation Instructions](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#downloads)

Comment: @alecxs thanks.. I have an Oppo A9 - specifically, OPPO A9 2020 Snapdragon.. Would those instructions apply to me or if not how would I adjust them?  Should I ask a question here specifically for rooting the Oppo A9?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the root file different if a custom rom is installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228253/is-the-root-file-different-if-a-custom-rom-is-installed)

Comment: maybe there is one additional step patching vbmeta or dtbo partition, but try the magisk boot patching + flash via fastboot first. no custom recovery TWRP required, only obtain a boot.img and follow Magisk Installation Instructions. or see 3.c) with correct stock ROM + 4.b) Magisk v8.0.5 usage is new/different + (5) fastboot

Comment: there is no development on xda how did you unlock bootloader? you can help others post your answer [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/oppo-a9-2020-rooting.4003265) (i will follow that thread and assist in rooting there as Android Enthusiasts is only Q&A site)

Comment: @alecxs Thanks. I have posted an answer in the thread you mentioned on how to unlock the boot loader

Comment: correction, I think I hadn't unlocked the bootloader!