# 100% Flash memory used by system/proc folder - Oppo find X3 lite - colorOS 12

Tags: insufficient-memory, system, oppo

I'm currently facing this issue: after the ColorOS 12 update on my OPPO find X3 lite, my phone was showing the warning of flash memory full (128 GB). Even removing files, cache, apps and other stuff, after very little time it was showing the warning again.

Long story short, I found that the system is creating multiple copies of the same folder under the path "system/proc/12566/task", there are currently 98 folders using roughly 1,3 GB each.

Is it a system bug? Should I try to remove these folders? Anyone's already faced this issue by chance?

Comment: `/system/proc` is not a real folder, therefore it occupies no space on flash. All the content is just data generated on-the-fly by the Linux kernel. https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html BTW: The term "memory" is ambiguous as it can refer to RAM memory or Flash memory. As there is no Android phone with 128GB RAM you seem to refer to flash memory, I have corrected that and the wrong RAM tag.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Robert, and thank you for the correction, yeah I definitely meant ROM memory (probably the ram tag has been autoadded). Does that mean that I can try to delete that folders?

Comment: there is only one writeable partition so the warning concerns /data only (even if it's named "System")

Comment: I understand. I haven't still rooted this phone so I don't have view access to /data folder. Would the root let me understand what's the real responsible of the memory usage? There's definitely something that's "burning" space without a clear reason...

Comment: @alecxs I'll check it right know and let you know, thank you for the help

Comment: Rooting the device would eliminate your requirement for storage analysis now, because in the rooting process a factory reset is performed so all data would be gone...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Is Using Up My Storage/Data on Android Phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215767)

Comment: @Robert well yeah that's true

Comment: @alecxs I just checked with adb, my /storage/emulated/0 folder is showing just 11.7GB of usage... What else may I check?

Comment: ColorOS RECOVERY is able to decrypt /data. not sure about root shell though, but someone claimed it provides availbility to install [unsigned](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223444/how-to-root-oppo-realme-2/224652#comment292416_224837) flashable zip files. that could be [utilized](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220648) to access /data without rooting

Comment: That means that I should install SU through ColorOS RECOVERY, did I get it right? Of course I'll perform a full backup before doing anything... thank you

Comment: No, do not install SuperSU. create your own (unsigned) flashable zip for `du` and try to install (will most likely fail). full backup is only possible in EDL mode btw

Comment: `/proc`, `/sys` etc. are kernel's virtual filesystems which reside in RAM. And they take very small amount of RAM - not more than a few MBs. Relevant details [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/230846/218526). Also related: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526).